# Realm: How to query for a property that is stored in an array?

Tags: swift, realm

So I have an array with memberEmails, now I would like to query for users that are not stored in this array:

```
var memberEmails: [String] = // ... is not empty

self.registeredUsers = self.realm.objects(AppUser).filter("email != '\(self.user.email!)' && '\(memberEmails)' !CONTAINS email")
```

The error message that is thrown:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "email != 'iphone5s@mail.com' && '["iphone5s@mail.com"]' !CONTAINS email"'
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use Swift's String interpolation to make queries, but rather NSPredicate's `%@` formatter:

```
var memberEmails: [String] = // ... is not empty

self.registeredUsers = self.realm.objects(AppUser.self).filter("email != %@ && NOT (email IN %@)", self.user.email, memberEmails)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it throws an error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "email != %@ && '%@ !CONTAINS email"'.
`

Comment: I had a typo in the format string, an extra apostrophe. I've removed it now.

Comment: That also throws an error. The creation of the `NSPredicate` seems to fail. `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "email != %@ && %@ !CONTAINS email"'`.

Comment: Maybe it's `NOT CONTAINS`? `"email != %@ && NOT(%@ CONTAINS email)"`.

Comment: Nope: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid value', reason: 'Expected object of type string for property 'email' on object of type 'AppUser', but received: ("ipad@mail.com", "iphone5s@mail.com")'`

Comment: @MJQZ1347 `CONTAINS` is string comparison operator like `BEGINSWITH`, `ENDSWITH`, etc. Maybe what you'd like to is `filter("email != %@ && NOT (email IN %@)", self.user.email, memberEmails)`? Use `IN` to check the object stored in an array.

Comment: Yes, Katsumi is right, sorry for not thinking of this. I'll update my answer.